# Docker pandas read excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, docker, xlsx

I'm a new in Docker, and I need to run a Flask app, but in this app, I need to read a xlsx file.

When I build my docker image, I have the excel file but Docker don't read it.

See the part of my code with the xlsx :

```
try :
    # Page PayPlug
    infos_pay = pd.read_excel('./app-infos.xlsx', sheet_name='payplug')
    secret_key = infos_pay.loc[0].tolist()
    payplug.set_secret_key(secret_key[0])
    # Page mail
    feuille_mail = pd.read_excel('./app-infos.xlsx', sheet_name='mail')
    infos_mail = feuille_mail.loc[0].tolist()
    
except :
    print("Can't read file")
```

And my docker file :

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./web_AuSpot.py" ]
```

When I use ls cmd in the cli of the image, I see the xlsx file, so why pandas can't read it ?

Thank you, I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting, the requirements.txt file and location where you see the file in the image?

Comment: The message error is the print in the try/except, i don't have another error.

The file xlsx is in the same location of the app.py

My image build correctly put return anything

Comment: use `except Exception as e:` then `print(e)` to get the error. Or, I would remove the try/except temporary to see the whole exception and stack trace. This is the most important clue to find out why your program is not able to read the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading excel files isn't necessary to pandas operation.  So you need to also list the xlrd package in your requirements file.  If that doesn't fix it you will need to list out the requirements.txt file and also add the docker error message would be helpful to put into your question.

Other possibilities are:

- Could be a file location problem.
- could be that pandas wasn't imported as pd (I don't see it in the code)

Comment: Thank you for your response

- The file location is good
- Pandas as imported like `from pandas as pd` so it's good

I'm going to try with the xlrd in the requirements file, see you after

Thank you very much

EDIT :
Don't work :/ it's very strange

Comment: OK,  this is the point you will need to post the docker log file for anyone to diagnose.

Comment: Ok It's done, the location file and excel was the problem, for the excel, I needed to use `openpyxl` in the requirements. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I remove the try expect and I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./web_AuSpot.py", line 46, in <module>
    infos_pay = pd.read_excel('/app-infos.xlsx', sheet_name='payplug')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    import_optional_dependency("xlrd", extra=err_msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 110, in import_optional_dependency
    raise ImportError(msg) from None
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
```

(I can't put it in a comment so I put it in)

EDIT :

I add the xrld in requirements, change the location path of the xlsx, and now I have this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./web_AuSpot.py", line 46, in <module>
    infos_pay = pd.read_excel('app-infos.xlsx', sheet_name='payplug')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 37, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 170, in open_workbook
    raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

Comment: I add `xrld==1.0.0` in the requirements for try

Comment: Ok so, It doesn't find the app-infos.xlsx, `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app-infos.xlsx'`

Comment: notice the difference in line `infos_pay = pd.read_excel('/app-infos.xlsx', sheet_name='payplug')` in first run and `infos_pay = pd.read_excel('app-infos.xlsx', sheet_name='payplug')` in second run. Looks like you have changed the location of the file between runs. Try putting the full path of the file (I assume it will be `/code/app-infos.xlsx`

Comment: Thank you Jordan, you helped me solve my problem especially with the try except thank you very much!